# Normal matching with Jquery on links not working

Tags: url, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get urls off a page that has this sort of code repeated- 
 `<a onmouseout="swho.alone.OnMouseOut(event)" onmouseover="swho.alone.showPopup(event, 'DR647E481', 'pra**', '', '', 'everyone', 'closed')" href="/SWApp/detailAction.do?key=DR647E481&search=pra**&soundex=&stanfordonly=&affilfilter=everyone&filters=closed">Ajay Prakash</a>`

using this code in Jquery - `$jq("#PublicResults a[href]")`

For some reason when I call `$jq("#PublicResults a[href]").text()` I get Ajay Prakash.

I'm not sure why and I'd like to know why.

But more than that, I'd like to know how to get only the URL.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT-
OK, the response below is giving me an undefined in the firebug console and I'm not sure why- to overcome that I tried -

```
$jq("#PublicResults a[href]").attr("href")
```

which gives me only the url for the page that I'm on, as opposed to all of the links - any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (not tested) -

```
$jq("#PublicResults a").attr("href")
```

Comment: when I enter that into the firebug console it gives me 'undefined'

Comment: also, aren't I doing that with the array notation?

Comment: '$jq("#PublicResults a[href]").text()' Will get you the text of any links that have a href attribute. What I've tried to do is return the value of the 'href' attribute.

Comment: that's really strange- because it's going undefined for me

Comment: If you go to the jsfiddle link, does that alert 'undefined'?

Comment: it doesn't- which is what is confusing me - the above html is also between dl and dt tags, if that changes anything